# Calling Docusign Rest API to get Envelope PDF is NOT showing changes

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the docusign Resp API v2.1 to execute the following:

1. Create an envelope using composite template.
2. Update fields in draft envelope using rest api.
3. Download pdf of envelope to preview changes made in step 2.

RESULT: NO Changes are shown.

I am using the following endpoint to download the document:
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/get/

According to the api documentation, the following parms should be sent to enable showing changes: /documents/combined?watermark=true&&show_changes=true

This was working up until recently.  I can see the changes made after executing step 2 above when logging into docusign and viewing the draft envelope through the docusign web portal. But when downloading the pdf through the api i am not seeing any updated tab data in the pdf itself.  Previously all required tabs were highlighted with red squares as well, now nothing is being highlight either.

This no longer seems to be working and I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the C# docusign SDK to do this.  Looks like they just pushed out a new version.  Using the latest version of the SDK solved my problem.